# Is GCC correct in requiring the constexpr specifier for this reference declaration?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

The code below doesn't compile under [GCC 5.3.0](https://goo.gl/2oyoCt) because the declaration of `r` is missing a `constexpr` specifier.

```
const int i = 1;
const int& r = i;
constexpr int j = r;
```

I believe the rejection is correct. How do I prove it using the working draft N4527?

Comment: Well, this code [_does_ compile with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6944ddade600d0d5).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, since we're using a reference, [expr.const]/(2.9) must not be violated. (2.9.1) applies, though:

> an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of
>   reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and 
>   either 
> — it is initialized with a constant expression

I.e. using `r` is fine, as long as the initializer - `i` - is a constant expression (this is shown below).
It's also necessary to check whether the l-t-r conversion in line 3 is legal, i.e. (2.7) must not be violated. However, (2.7.1) applies:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to 
>  — a
>   non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to
>   a complete non-volatile `const` object with a preceding
>   initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or

…so that's fine as well, since the (g)lvalue is `r`, and it refers to `i` - which is a non-volatile `const` object with a constant expression initializer (`1`).

We postponed showing that `i` is actually a constant expression, and once that's out of the way, we need to show that `r` is a constant expression.
[expr.const]/5 pertains to that:

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
>   expression whose value is an object where, for that object and its
>   subobjects:
>
> - each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression, and
> - if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past
>     the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null
>     pointer value.
>
> An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if it is an object with static storage duration that is
>   either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a
>   function.

Since `i` is, in the above context, a (g)lvalue, it has to be a permitted result of a constant expression - which it is, since it has static storage duration and certainly isn't a temporary. Thus `i` is a constant expression.

`r` is, however, treated as a prvalue in line 3. Since we already established that `r` is a core constant expression, we solely need to check the bullet points. They're clearly met, though.

Hence **the code is well-formed in namespace scope**. It won't be in local scope, as `i` wouldn't be a permitted result of a constant expression anymore. [Clang gives a comprehensive error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c003aa3056096af).

Comment: You still need to prove that `r` is initialized with a constant expression. To show that `i` is a constant expression you have to prove that the value of `i` refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression, according to §5.20/5.

Comment: @Belloc That's nearly trivial, therefore not in my answer.

Comment: It may be trivial for you, not for me.

Comment: @Belloc Okay, I added it. :-)

Comment: But the clause says `whose value refers to an entity`, and the value of `i` is 1. Then I ask: how does 1 refer to an entity that is an object with static storage duration ...?

Comment: @Belloc A glvalue expression refers to an entity. The (id-)expression `i` refers to an entity declared in namespace scope, which has static storage duration and name `i`. `1` was the initializer. (`i` is not a reference, but even if it was, it would be referring to a temporary with value `1`, and since that temporary satisfies the bullet points, it's still [working fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a36e6b25727acfc).)

Comment: That's not my understanding. The clause says: `A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression **whose** value refers to an entity.` (my emphasis).

Comment: @Belloc I believe "value" isn't meant to refer to the actual value of the expression after l-t-r conversion. It's the same thing that "value" in "value computation" means: We need to perform "value" computations for left-hand side operands in assignment expressions, although the value of the object is irrelevant (and could be indeterminate). Really, the value is the identity of the entity that the expression designates. 
However, if I'm wrong, the sentence is defective. :o)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98983/discussion-between-columbo-and-belloc).

Comment: @Columbo I think that use of "value" is defective. The term "value computation" is itself a defined term. I don't think it is the computation of a value, but it denotes the thing called "value computation".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah, I think so, too. I filed the issue report.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Where exactly is "value computation" defined?

Comment: @Columbo hm, weird. it doesn't seem to define that anywhere. The nearest thing seems to be the one you quoted (" in general includes
both value computations (including .."), but it's not italic.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That begs for another DR, doesn't it?

Comment: @Columbo IMO yes because it has normative significance. Since we have a definition of "value" that isn't compatible with the meaning of "computation of value" for the term "value computation", I would say we need a definition for it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I have what I think is a proper definition. Before I submit the report, would you mind checking it? (I'd PM it.)

Comment: @Columbo In reference to `An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object ...` could you show me an example of an object with static storage duration that is also a temporary ?

Comment: @Belloc The object referred to in `static const int& i = 0;`

Comment: @Columbo That was great. I've never heard of an lvalue temporary. (+1)

Comment: @Belloc well it is not an lvalue temporary. `i` is not a temporary. But the object that initializes `i` is a temporary (and the synthesized initializer expression that refers to that temporarary hasn't got a value category attached, the last time I checked).

Comment: @Columbo sorry for the late response. Please go ahead and PM it to me. I can't promise that I'm able to verify its validity though. I'm not too familiar with the subjects surrounding value computation.

Comment: @Belloc `i` is bound to a temporary initialized with `0`. The temporary obtains static storage duration by being bound to a reference having static storage duration. However, temporaries haven't got a value category since they're not expressions but objects.

Comment: @Columbo interesting note: my DR that resulted in the explicit notion of "temporary expressions" was based on the phenomenon that the spec already talked about temporary expressions without defining them explicitly. For example, "The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The noun "temporary" designates an object, not an expression, i.e. "prvalue temporary." is wrong AFAICS.

Comment: @Columbo `i is bound to a temporary initialized with 0` That's exactly what I thought, but I have to concede that I missed this: `However, temporaries haven't got a value category since they're not expressions but objects.` Thanks.

Comment: @Columbo I agree that according to current wording is wrong (but just as wrong as other wordings about lifetime extensions of temporaries). However, not anymore after http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3918.html has been applied.

Comment: This also provides a sound basis for life-extending things like `temporaryObject.nonReferenceMember` which currently are lifetime extended despite refering to a non-temporary object, but using a hacky wording. In essence, there is an attribute-inheritance from the object expression into the member access expression of the attribute "temporary", although the actual current wording doesn't express that clearly. Similar things for `(e1, temporary)` (which is kind of clearer because the same object is being referenced, but not anymore with the same expression either!).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Btw., I added you on Jabber (I think? My client shows some weird error message concerning DNS resolution for your server?). However, I realized that a proper resolution will probably require more definitions (of e.g. "a value" itself), so I'll draft a paper and send you that once it's done.

Comment: @Columbo i don't use jabber often, these days. possibly the server I used back then is offline now. I will be happy to read your paper drafts =)