# Is an lvalue reference subjected to an lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++17

I always thought that a reference would be subjected to an *lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion*, as any other *glvalue*, when used in an *expression*. Nevertheless, it seems like, every time a reference is used in an *expression*, it is handled in bullet point (2.9) of [[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) instead of bullet point (2.7) (in C++14, or C++1z).

Take for example the reference `r` below, used to initialize variable `j`. Is it subjected to an *lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion*?

```
const int i = 1;
constexpr int& r = i
constexpr int j = r;
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465086/1042389) the reference `r` is handled in bullet point (2.9) of [expr.const]/2 and not in bullet point 2.7, as I would expect. Why is this?

Comment: The bullets in [expr.const]/2 don't "handle" anything. Every bullet needs to be satisfied in order for the expression to be a core constant expression.

Comment: Then why isn't bullet (2.7) satisfied by the reference `r`? Could you explain? I mean why isn't one of the sub-bullets in (2.7) satisfied?

Comment: What part about *every bullet* is hard to understand? You need to satisfy *all* of them, not *one* of them.

Comment: Did you see my edit above?

Comment: Whether or not you satisfy 2.7, you still have to satisfy 2.9, and 2.10, and 2.11, and 2.12, and so forth... ... If it doesn't satisfy 2.9, it's not a core constant expression, regardless of whether 2.7 is met.

Comment: If one of the sub-bullets in (2.7) is satisfied, I already know that the expression is a core-constant-expression. I don't need to go up to (2.9). That's my understanding.

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: I just can't agree with this. [expr.const]/2 says: "A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following expressions:". Thus, if bullet point (2.7) is not satisfied, because one of its sub-bullets is satisfied, I know by the paragraph 2 above, that the expression evaluates a core constant expression.

Comment: By your logic, every expression that doesn't evaluate `this` is a core constant expression.

Comment: I see what you mean. But in this case, the answer that I referred to above, to be entirely correct, should have indicated that bullet point (2.7) is not satisfied, i.e., one of its sub-bullets was satisfied as well. Isn't that correct?

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs because it is explicitly specified to occur in a given context (for example, for the ternary conditional operator, see [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#7)). But it is listed in clause 4 so it is an implicit standard conversion; like all other implicit standard conversions, it occurs *when needed.* For example, a glvalue of type `int` will be implicitly converted to a prvalue when used as the operand of an arithmetic expression since its stored value is required.

In the case of `constexpr int j = r`, yes, the glvalue expression `r` undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, since this initialization requires the stored value. Although it isn't explicitly specified that reading the stored value of an object invokes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, this fact must obviously be true in the context of the entire standard, as well as the C standard, where the term "rvalue" is not used, but instead the analogous concept of the *lvalue conversion* refers to the conversion of an lvalue into "the value stored in the designated object".